# TypeError Object[object object] has no method SubSelf, TypeError Object[object object] has no method intersectsPlane

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

While working on a WebGL project using the excellent Sim.js and Three.js libraries, i've stumbled upon the next problem:

Somewhere along the way, it uses the next constructor for THREE.Ray:

```js
var ray = new THREE.Ray( this.camera.position, vector.subSelf( this.camera.position ).normalize() );
```

where vector is Vector3,

which triggers the following error:

TypeError Object[object object] has no method subSelf.

I checked the documentation from the Three.js that i'm using and the method on vector3 that approached the most this one is

```js
.sub( v ) Vector3
```

i tried changing this and a new error shows up on this call:

```js
var intersects = ray.intersectScene( this.scene );
```

which again throws an error because, when i check, ray doesn't have a intersectsPlane method

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the THREE.js api changed a while back.

`Vector3`'s `subSelf()` [is now simply `sub()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js#L127), as you discovered.

And `Ray`'s `intersectsPlane()` [looks like it should be `intersectPlane()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Ray.js#L130).

If you want complex scene intersection, [you probably want to use `Raycaster`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js) instead. Docs: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/56/#Reference/Core/Raycaster

Three.js documentation is not the best thing ever... However, a lot of insight can be gleaned from simply [inspecting the source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src).

Comment: actually i got it wrong the first time, the original code is ray.IntersectScene, which doesn't exist and i replaced it with intersectPlane being the only intersect existing in Ray.js, which sprungs a new "cannot call method dot of undefine" error

Comment: according to the three.js migration wiki, intersectScene no longer exists and it recommends using intersectObjects(array), any idea who owns this method?

Comment: @MaxRodriguezCollada You don't want a `Ray`, they don't do complex collision anymore.  `Ray` is now a purely mathematical construct, but _casting_ the ray is now done by a new class called `Raycaster`. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js